# Ignore brief mouse click/releases

Tags: xorg, mouse, input

The switch contacts in my mouse are going, and rather than open it up yet again and clean them or try to hunt down a replacement switch (or buy a new mouse) I would like to solve this problem via software.

Is there a way I can tell the Linux input system to watch the current state of the mouse button, and only send a press/release event when the average value over the last few milliseconds has gone to one extreme?

This way when the mouse button is held down, the very short "button release" pulses from the failing switch would be ignored, so I could drag and drop without any problems.  Likewise clicking once should be slow enough that it won't get processed as a double-click.

I would be happy with a udev/evdev or Xorg solution, as being a mouse it only needs to work in Xorg.

Comment: At least for keyboards, this behaviour can usually be set in the *accessibility* settings.The keyword is *debouncing*.

Comment: @jofel: I have looked in the Linux kernel source and I can only find debouncing references for specific devices with buttons, not a general debounce for a keyboard or mouse.  And the Xorg config file doesn't seem to have any debounce options I can find.  So any specific pointers for kernel/uinput/evdev or Xorg would be much appreciated!